# Populate DateTime from a string

Tags: c#

I would like to populate a DateTime structure from a string, but it is not working:
This is the format I have: 
i.e.: "6/4/09 11:10 AM"

This is what I am using but it is not working
DateTime dttm = DateTime.ParseExact(dttmString, "d/m/yy H:mm tt", format);

Any idea?
Thanks

Tony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your month.  Month is "M".  "m" is minutes.  "H" is 24 hour time.  Here's a reference page for datetime.parseextact and datetime.tostring format strings.  http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

Answer (score 1):

use "d/M/yy h:mm tt", format);

Change 'm' to 'M' for month and change 'H' to 'h' for hour.

Answer (score 0):

try using a capital 'M' for month.